# Use of "would be" vs. "is"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> She has five kids. I can imagine how busy she would be.

Is the use of would be right in this sentence? What about

> She has five kids. I can imagine how busy she is.

Are both correct? Do they mean different things?

Comment: They are both correct and they both pretty much mean the same thing: The woman is very busy, and you can understand that just by thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I can imagine how busy she would be."

is your imagination speaking. You're picturing that she's probably busy, with no evidence to say that she in fact is. It's not that she stated anything, or you saw anything; you've just imagined that she's busy all the time, so cannot *definitively* say that she *is* busy (merely "would be").

> "I can imagine how busy she is" (with an implied "*all* the *time*!")

is agreeing with a statement or presented fact. If someone said "She's really busy", or you saw her running around, then this second version is better. Although it uses the word "imagine", replace it with the similar word "picture" - you're using your imagination to picture her running around *all* the *time*. In the face of this evidence, it would be slightly negative to say the first version.